# nginx redirect localhost and subdomain

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I am trying to put a development server in place on the same server as the production server. The two will run on different ports, and one will be accessible via `prod.example.com` and the other via `dev.example.com`. There is a DNS `A` record in place already.

I would like the following :

```
    www.example.com          => port 9393
    www1.example.com         => port 9393
    anysubdomain.example.com => port 9393
    dev.example.com          => port 19393
```

Here is what I have so far (not working) :

```
http {

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root /var/www/...;

        Location / {
            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:9393/;
        }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name dev.*;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:19393;
        }   
    }
}
```

I've seen the following Q/A :

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649444/redirect-subdomain-to-port-nginx-flask
- [nginx: "server_name" resolution order?](https://serverfault.com/questions/240507/nginx-server-name-resolution-order)

Comment: Could a `default` help ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any error log? (it would be logging to default nginx error log - most probable /var/log/nginx/error.log )

I think the most probable you will get is:

> "http" directive is not allowed here in ...

If I'm not wrong, you shouldn't include server directives inside http (just remove http{}) and please, add some error logs if it's not working after.